# How do i get my sql format to change to days not numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, date-formatting

[image]

1. Create a view that lists the guests who have reservations that begin on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, or Thursday. Include the following columns:

   • the day of the week spelled out fully (e.g., Monday)

```
CREATE VIEW V_Guest_1
AS
SELECT CONCAT(last_name,',',first_name) AS Guest_Name,
DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date,'%m/%d/%Y')AS check_in_date,
DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date,'%w') AS Day_Name
FROM viewreservations
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date,'%w'),last_name,first_name;
```

Comment: This sounds like homework. What exactly is your error?

Comment: it is, I am having a syntax error

Comment: Add the error to the post

Comment: `view_name` sounds like wrong table name. Is it valid table name?

Comment: The second argument of DATE_FORMAT should be quoted. `DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date,"%W")`

Comment: you're right! I changed it to
CREATE VIEW V_Guest_1

AS

SELECT CONCAT(last_name,',',first_name) AS Guest_Name,

DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date,'%m/%d/%Y')AS check_in_date,

DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date,'%w') AS Day_Name

FROM viewreservations

ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date,'%w'),last_name,first_name;

Comment: however, the day names show up as numbers not days.

For example 1,2,3,4 instead of monday,tuesday,wednesday

Comment: Well that's part of the homework assignment ;)

Comment: yes, but is there any dateformat i could use?

Comment: Learning to use this manual will be very valuable: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work in MySQL for outputting the day name. (Capital W makes it non numeric)

```
DAYNAME(check_in_date)
DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date,'%W')
```